# How do I test dictionary-equality with Python's doctest-package?

Tags: python, dictionary, doctest

I'm writing a doctest for a function that outputs a dictionary. The doctest looks like

```
>>> my_function()
{'this': 'is', 'a': 'dictionary'}
```

When I run it, it fails with

```
Expected:
    {'this': 'is', 'a': 'dictionary'}
Got:
    {'a': 'dictionary', 'this': 'is'}
```

My best guess as to the cause of this failure is that doctest isn't checking dictionary equality, but `__repr__` equality. [This post](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-March/098177.html) indicates that there's some way to trick doctest into checking dictionary equality. How can I do this?

Comment: since dict is unordered, you can't use the dict as it is. you must transform it into an ordered object

Comment: The answers listed below are all in the doctest documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#warnings

Comment: @ornoone  But why?  They are equal objects, that's what doctest should be checking.

Comment: as said in accepted answer, it is the __repr__ for your both object that is checked, not their content. since `repr(a) != repr(b)` doctest think your objects is differents. event if `a == b` is ok. i think that is so because doctest is in __doc__, and should be easyly readable and with the repr check, it is readable.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Doctest doesn't check `__repr__` equality, per se, it just checks that the output is exactly the same. You have to ensure that whatever is printed will be the same for the same dictionary. You can do that with this one-liner:

```
>>> sorted(my_function().items())
[('a', 'dictionary'), ('this', 'is')]
```

Although this variation on your solution might be cleaner:

```
>>> my_function() == {'this': 'is', 'a': 'dictionary'}
True
```

Comment: Your solution is cleaner but it will fail to tell you what my_function actually evaluated to.

Comment: the pprint solution looks much cleaner, see charlax's answer

Comment: but what if it's a documentation example and I want to show a realistic input and realistic output?  Is there a way to get it to check equality instead of exact strings?

Comment: The second variation you gave worked perfectly for my simple doctest. Thanks!

Comment: the `pprint`-solution doesn't always work for `set` doctests - no guaranteed order. If you want to know afterwards what It was evaluated to, you can do `my_function() == {'this': 'is', 'a': 'dictionary'} or my_function()`

Answer (score 41):

Another good way is to use `pprint` (in the standard library).

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint({"second": 1, "first": 0})
{'first': 0, 'second': 1}
```

According to its source code, it's sorting dicts for you:

http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/pprint.py#l158

```
items = _sorted(object.items())
```

Comment: it would be nice, but python devs [don't recommend this](https://bugs.python.org/issue20310) because they don't guarantee pprint stability across versions.

Comment: also, this solution necessarily work for other datatypes (such as set).

Comment: Advantage here is once the assertion fails, `pprint` will show a helful diff. If `pprint` implementation changes between Python version, well, we need to adjust our tests or just duplicate the implementation in our code to keep it stable.

Answer (score 16):

I ended up using this. Hacky, but it works.

```
>>> p = my_function()
>>> {'this': 'is', 'a': 'dictionary'} == p
True
```

Comment: I don't think that's hacky (although I'd write `p == {etc}`) -- that's the first recommended technique in the relevant section of [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#warnings).

Comment: why not `my_function() == {'this': 'is', 'a': 'dictionary'}`?

Comment: The disadvantage here is once the assertion fails, you do not know which keys, values exactly are wrong. Solution with `pprint` would show a helpful diff.

Answer (score 3):

turn it into a list via dict.items() and then sort it ...

```
>>> l = my_function().items()
>>> l.sort()
>>> l
[('a', 'dictionary'), ('this', 'is')]
```

Comment: or as a one-liner: `sorted( my_function().items())`

Answer (score 3):

You can create an instance of `unittest.TestCase` class inside your doctests, and use it to compare dictionaries:

```
def my_function(x):
    """
    >>> from unittest import TestCase
    >>> t = TestCase()

    >>> t.assertDictEqual(
    ...     my_function('a'),
    ...     {'this': 'is', 'a': 'dictionary'}
    ... )

    >>> t.assertDictEqual(
    ...     my_function('b'),
    ...     {'this': 'is', 'b': 'dictionary'}
    ... )

    """
    return {'this': 'is', x: 'dictionary'}
```

Note: this approach is better than simply checking if dictionaries are equal, because it will show diff between the two dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

Most of it has been already said here.. anyway JSYK: there is a dedicated section in doctest documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/doctest.html#warnings

Answer (score 1):

I found it useful to use the [deepdiff](https://github.com/seperman/deepdiff) package in my doctests when testing arbitrarily nested data. For example:

```
def something_complicated():
    """
    >>> from deepdiff import DeepDiff
    >>> DeepDiff(something_complicated(),
    ...          {'expected': {'output': ['a', 'b', 'c']}},
    ...          ignore_order=True)
    {}
    """
    items = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    random.shuffle(items)
    return {'expected': {'output': items}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is having a stable representation of dictionaries (i.e. with sorted keys). Well, we can use the built-in `json` module for that:

```py
def foobar():
    """Foobar returns a dict.

    >>> print(json.dumps(foobar(), indent=2, sort_keys=True))
    {
      "bar": "abc",
      "foo": 123
    }
    """
    ...
```

Using `json.dumps(foobar(), ...)` (or `json.dump(foobar(), sys.stdout, ...)`) will not only provide a stable representation with sorted keys, but also pretty-printed with newlines and indentation.

Note, however, that not all objects are JSON serializable. While this approach works fine for most basic types (`bool`, `int`, `float`, `str`, `list`), and even works for nested structures; it will represent a `tuple` the same way as a `list`, and it doesn't work for `set` objects. (And, of course, be careful with `float` precision.)