# Correct way of unit testing __repr__ with dict

Tags: python, unit-testing, eval

Say I have a class given by:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<%s: %r>" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.kwargs)
```

`__repr__` isn't really important for core functionality, but occasionally gets called for logging, shows up in stack traces, and such, so I'd like to unit-test it.

The problem is similar to [that faced when using doctest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549429/how-do-i-test-dictionary-equality-with-pythons-doctest-package), but I'd rather keep any complexity (like sorting) in the test function and not in `__repr__`.

Right now I'm using `eval` and `re` to extract the dictionary from the `repr()` call, but I wanted to check if there were non-`eval` alternatives out there that people used.

```py
def test_repr():
    retval = repr(MyClass(a=1, b=2, c=3))
    match = re.match("^<MyClass: ({.*})>\Z", retval)
    assert match
    assert eval(match.group(1)) == dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You only need to check that the `kwargs` dictionary is correctly being `repr`esented in the output, so just pass zero or one keyword arguments:

```
>>> repr(MyClass(foo='bar')) == "<MyClass: {'foo': 'bar'}>"
True
>>> repr(MyClass()) == '<MyClass: {}>'
True
```

Then ordering doesn't matter at all.

---

If you decide to stick with evaluating the extracted dictionary, use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead of vanilla `eval`. I would also use a slice rather than `re`, as you know the expected format:

```
>>> '<MyClass: {}>'[10:-1]
'{}'
```

Comment: In the real code, `kwargs` gets built rather than simply passed-in, so I can't test with the single-key or empty dicts. `literal_eval` is a good tip, though. Thanks!