# Compare unordered containers by content in docstrings

Tags: python, testing, python-sphinx

Checking the output of an unordered container (such as dict) fails because there are multiple ordering options. For example, this simple example can be written as this:

```
>>> dict(x=1, y=2)
{'y': 2, 'x': 1}
```

or this:

```
>>> dict(x=1, y=2)
{'x': 1, 'y': 2}
```

This is a pain when you want to doctest the documentation. Most of the time I avoid doing this either by rewriting the example using another container or adding a `# doctest: +SKIP`.

But this is inconvenient. Is there another doctest option in Sphinx that compares containers by content?

Comment: `>>> dict(x=1, y=2) == {'x': 1, 'y': 2}` next line: `True`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski for small dictionaries is fine, but as it gets longer does not look good. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15549429/407651

Comment: Thanks @mzjn This is a solution similar to what was suggested before. I ended up writing a custom output checker.